# WebStorm 2016.1.3 React attributes wrong autocomplete

Tags: javascript, reactjs, phpstorm, webstorm, jsx

I use WebStorm 2016.1.3 with ReactJS. In my JSX code I want to use IDE autocomplete for tags, but it works wrong.

IDE suggest me `onchange=""`

[image]

but I need `onChange={}`.
This problem also there is in another attributes.

I tried to use "React Templates" plugin but still it doesn't fix the problem.
Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: install react.d.ts in the project or use WS 2016.2 EAP

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! But can you explane why it will fix the problem? As I understand you propose use TypeScript, but at the moment my code is not TS. Can you clearify your idea? Thanks.

Comment: WS 2016.1 doesn't have any information about react attributes (onchange is a regular html attirubute). But if you have the react.d.ts file WS uses information from 'react.d.ts' for providing the attributes (in javascript & typescript). See https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2015/10/working-with-reactjs-in-webstorm-coding-assistance/ for more information

Answer (score 1):

Problem: WebStorm suggest '`onclick`' instead of the correct react attribute '`onClick`' (and the same behaviour for other event attributes onchange, etc ..) + there is no completion for special Non-DOM attributes '`key`', '`ref`'.

WebStorm 2016.2 (EAP at the moment) solves the issue.

If you want to get correct attributes for WebStorm version < 2016.2 you can add to the project 'react.d.ts' file or install 'react' external library  ( see more information here: [WebStorm Blog: Working with ReactJS in WebStorm: Coding Assistance](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2015/10/working-with-reactjs-in-webstorm-coding-assistance/) ). Moreover code completion with the library will be much better.